# xcode image size isn't consistent through ios models

Tags: ios, xcode, image, swift, size

I am aware this question must have been asked before, but after 2 hours of searching and failure to find a working answer, I decided to ask again.

As you all know, each iOS model has a different screen size. However when I insert my logo (or any image) into my app, it maintains a specific size for whatever iOS model I preview it in, therefore it is too small on the 6+, yet doesn't fit on the screen on the 4.

Using code or not, how can I make my images be the same scale on each iOS model?

Answer (score 0):

To achieve what you are asking for you can just use Constraints throughout your project. The easiest way would probably be to just make an `aspect ratio` constraint on your image view. However that will only keep the ratio of width to height the same. In order to make it fit onto all the screens, you should simply add some constraint to your image view, as for example `trailing space to container margin`. You can set those through here:

[image: screenshot]

If you set for example 0,0,0 then this will keep your logo in the upper part of yur screen and always fitting into the screen. You may also want to consider adding a height constraint, so your logo doesn't get compressed.

Hope that helps,

Julian

Answer (score -1):

Within your image casset you need to have an @3x and an @2x, then it will choose the right image size for the right device.

Comment: In your project files you will see an item called "images.xcassets", click on that and it will show you your images (if that's what you've been using). When you click on an image you can set different size images for "@1x", "@2x", "@3x". I would recommend using this rather than loading an image like UIImage(named: "myImage.png"), using the cassettes means you can call it without the .png on the end of the name as well.

Comment: BTW it's asset, not casset. And .xcassets is [Asset Catalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html)

Comment: There are no images in my Images.xcassets area, and I can't find how to add them even after searching the web. I have no idea why this has to be so difficult. :(

Comment: You literally just drag the images into the images.xcasset. A little tip, if you name your difference size images with "@2x" and "@3x" then they will automatically be put into the correct slot

Comment: So I put all my images into the Images.xcassets folder, made them all have their three scales (1x, 2x, 3x) and it didn't seem to change a thing.